# tkinter messagebox without buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

In my program I just need to notify user to not press a physical button om a system with no keyboad or mouse,
want to popup a Wait message that disapears when the system is again ready

Comment: Please provide more details related with your question, like your actual code and why it does not work as you expected. This makes easier to understand your problem and help you.

Comment: A `tkMessageBox` is just a `Dialog` with some standard buttons added. So, instead of trying to figure out how to hack around the message box to avoid the buttons, why not just use a `Dialog` directly?

Answer (score 5):

There are two reasons you don't want a message box here.

First, the whole point of a message box is that it's a modal dialog with some standardized buttons, and you don't want those buttons.

Second, the whole point of a modal dialog is that it's modal—it runs its own event loop, and doesn't return until the dialog is dismissed. This means (unless you're using background threads) your app can't do anything while displaying it.

---

The first problem is easy to solve. `tkMessageBox` is just a simple wrapper around `tkCommonDialog.Dialog`. It's worth looking at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/lib-tk/tkMessageBox.py) to see just how simple it is to construct a dialog box that does what you want. But `tkSimpleDialog.Dialog` is even simpler than `tkCommonDialog` (hence the name). For example:

```
class WaitDialog(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, title, message):
        self.message = message
        Dialog.__init__(self, parent, title=title, message=message)
    def body(self, master):
        Label(self, text=self.message).pack()
    def buttonbox(self):
        pass

def wait(message):
    WaitDialog(root, title='Wait', message=message)
```

That's all it takes to create a modal dialog with no buttons. [Dialog Windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm) and the source to [`tkSimpleDialog`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/lib-tk/tkSimpleDialog.py) have more details.

---

The second problem is even easier to solve: If you don't want a modal dialog, then all you want is a plain old `Toplevel`. You may want it to be [`transient`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.transient-method), so it stays on top of the master, hides with it, doesn't show up on the taskbar, etc., and you may want to configure all kinds of other things. But basically, it's this simple:

```
def wait(message):
    win = Toplevel(root)
    win.transient()
    win.title('Wait')
    Label(win, text=message).pack()
    return win
```

Now you can call `wait()` and continue to run:

```
def wait_a_sec():
    win = wait('Just one second...')
    root.after(1000, win.destroy)

root = Tk()
button = Button(root, text='do something', command=wait_a_sec)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is almost working for me.. I'm using your Wait funtion but calling it directly as win=wait("just a sec") but it doesn't show up until the function it's in is done and then When it shows it's below my root window and there is no text and the win.destroy raises an error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'

Comment: @Blanius: I'd have to see the code you've written to debug it. But it sounds like you're trying to do something slow and blocking in the middle of the button command. You can't _ever_ do that in an event-loop-based app like a typical GUI; if you don't return quickly, the event loop doesn't run, and the whole GUI freezes.